# How to append specific html to a Django code block using only Python/Django?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-templates

I have a form I'm working with in Django.
I have a built in error message I'm trying to get to render on the form.
My first step is to get the error message to render on the form and then I will go into the function and tweak when it shows up.
My problem emerges when it comes to doing it in python.
Normally, my preferred way would be to JQuery for the footer and use JavaScript to append/prepend the HTML. Then set it to show/hide based on conditionals.

However, for this I am wanting to do it in Python to make it easier for the people working w/ me.

Here's an example of the error message HTML I would like to use for appending to something else in JS.

```
error_field.append('<em for="name" class="form-error-message text-danger">');
```

Here is an example of the Django Code Block I would like to add it within

```
{% block form-footer %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this within Python/Django? To be clear, I can figure out the conditional stuff myself. Just the rendering of the specific HTML/CSS error class I have already created. I should be able to do the conditional/function part of this myself.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly: You want to update the web page displayed to the user after they sent the form data? If you want to do this on server side (in python), you will need a page reload. This is something, one usually does not want. Usually, some asynchronous javascript is used for this, isn't it? Maybe you want to send the whole page contents in the asynchronous response? I am not sure, I understand.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Hey there! I'm just trying to add in a piece of HTML & CSS (A piece of warning text I have been using throughout my program for warning text.) If I can just get it to display within the template I can look at handling the conditionals. Unfortunately I am struggling just getting the HTML snippet to appear on my footer.

Answer (score 0):

I can just show you an example, this is a part of my project

**views.py**

```
try:
        user=User.objects.get(username=username)
    except:
        messages.info(request,'username does not exist')
        return redirect('login')

 return render(request,'users/login-register.html')
```

**html**

```
{% if messages %}
       {% for i in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert--{{i.tags}}">
                <p class="alert__message">{{i}}</p>
                <button  class="alert__close">x</button>
            </div>
       {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

You can use this anywhere in your html page. This is a common page, and everything in here is extended. And of course this is an example similar to your problem. Check it out if you want